# Google Cloud VM - googleAuthR library no called error

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-auth-library

I have an R script that I run in google cloud environment, it helps me pull google analytics data and then I store it in storage. I call the googleAuthR library in one line of my script but I keep getting the same error. Has anyone had this problem before or can help?

I call the library like this:

```
library(googleAuthR)
library(googleCloudStorageR)
```

and error text i get:

```
Error in library(googleAuthR) : there is no package called ‘googleAuthR’
```

Comment: Could you please give us some more details? What Google Cloud environment are talking about? Are you using a [GCE VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute)?  [AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine)? [Other](https://cloud.google.com/products)? How did you install this library? and R? Any other information/setting that would be useful to know? Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as it's always useful for the StackOverflow Community to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your R installation cannot find the package. Probably it is not installed where R is looking for it.

To fix it, just open R from a terminal and execute:

```r
install.packages("googleAuthR");
```

and

```r
install.packages("googleCloudStorageR");
```

Remember that you will need to pass your Google credentials to work with cloud storage (for instance in a .json file, and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable - see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started ).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, I tried what you said but this time I'm facing this error. """Error in install.packages("googleAuthR") : unable to install packages"""